# Continue method execution without waiting for other method execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to call a method inside some method and do not want the process to wait or take time on other method completion.

like this

```
public ActionResult Insert(int userId)
{
     _userService.Insert(userId);
     SyncUserInSomeOtherCollection(userId);
     return new EmptyResult();
}

private SyncUserInSomeOtherCollection(int userId)
{
  //Do Sync work which will actually take some time
}
```

I want to make SyncUserInSomeOtherCollection() work in such a way so that the main method return result without any wait.

I tried to run a task like this

```
Task.Run(async () => await SyncUserInSomeOtherCollection(userId)).Result;
```

But not sure if this a good approach to follow.

Comment: Is it a problem if the work never completes (e.g. the API gets restarted)?

Comment: Since your method isnt async, `Task.Run(() => SyncUserInSomeOtherCollection(userId));` however be aware this is fire an forget, and if your AppPool recycles it wont get done

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43104036/9678775

Comment: @TheGeneral, so what I should do here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code that you shared, I assume you're working on ASP.NET. I've come across same scenario and found QueueBackgroundWorkItem to work for me, it also allows you to have graceful shutdown of your long running task when Worker Process is stopped / shutdown.

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(cancellationToken =>
{
  if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    //Do Action
  }
  else
  {
    //Handle Graceful Shutdown
  }
}
```

There are more ways to accomplish this. I suggest you go through this [excellent article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) by Scott Hanselman.